# CDC error - Error converting data type varchar to uniqueidentifier

Tags: sql-server, replication, sql-server-2014, change-data-capture

I have CDC and Replication configured on an Always On cluster.
I had to patch the SQL Server on Node 1 so I failed over the instance to node 2 and started patching node1.

After about an hour one of the log reader agent jobs started failing with the below error

> "The process could not execute  sp_replcmds..."

When I looked at the start of the failure in history, it says

> "Failed to insert rows into Change Data Capture change tables."

So I queried `sys.dm_cdc_errors` and the error was

> Error converting data type varchar to uniqueidentifier.

I am a noob with CDC.  Looks like it has nothing to do with Replication and its a CDC error.

Looking for suggestions on how to narrow down the issue, may be to the table causing the error?

**Update**
Now another log reader agent is failing with the similar error.

> Procedure or function sp_batchinsert_1350295870 has too many arguments
>   specified. Failed to insert rows into Change Data Capture change
>   tables.

Answer (score 0):

I think its the same as [this](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/165654/cdc-capture-job-failure-ct-table-column-changes-after-applying-2014-sp2cu4/169134)

But I was upgrading to SP2 CU7.  Anyway I disabled and re-enable the CDC and the log reader agent resumed.